# what number does the Zend_Dom_Query element count start at?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have just begun using Zend_Dome_Query and although this seems like a basic question to ask it can be too easy to asume the answer. I was wondering if the start counts for elements within a DOM starts at [0] or [1]. So for example:

```
$dom->queryXpath('//div[@id="foo"]/span[1]');
```

Would this select the first span element or the second? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indexes (positions) are 1 based.

so `/span[1]` is the first child.

Hope it helps